# What does this code getQueryStringParameter do?

Tags: 2013, javascript, query-string, front-end

I would like to know what this code does?
I am using it almost all the time but I don't know what it does.

```
function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
var params =
document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
var strParams = "";
for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
    var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
    if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
        return singleParam[1];
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It extracts **one** named parameter from the QueryString (URL)

```
http://domainname.com/page.aspx?parameter1=xxx&parameter2=yyy

var value=getQueryStringParameter('parameter1');
```

It is used in many examples and most of the time **not necessary** (*and bloats your code*)
because SharePoint has multiple implementations in core libraries

Usage depends on whether you want to check for non-existing values or CaSe matching

## (init.js) GetUrlKeyValue

```
var value=GetUrlKeyValue( 'parameter1' );
```

*returns an empty string "" if the parameter does not exist*

**GetUrlKeyValue( parameter , [maintain encoded value] , [url] , [ignorecase] )**

[encoded] - Boolean,    false(default) decodes value with [decodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)
                        true: maintains the original string

[url] - String          use another string, default: window.location.href (current URL)

[ignorecase] - Boolean  when true ignores case

## (init.js) JSRequest

```
JSRequest.EnsureSetup();
var value=JSRequest.QueryString['parameter1'];
```

*returns `undefined` if the parameter does not exist*

You have to do the `JSRequest.EnsureSetup()` `yourself as SharePoint does not seem to use its own code on each and every page.

JSRequest at least builts a `QueryString` object, so you only have to `EnsureSetup()` once (per page).
The `getQueryStringParameter` and `GetUrlKeyValue` functions execute the same code over and over for each and every call.

#### Even Microsoft duplicates functionality:

## (SP.init.js) SP.ScriptHelpers.getUrlQueryPairs

Even more SharePoint code that does the same

```
 var QS = SP.ScriptHelpers.getUrlQueryPairs(document.location.href)
 var value=QS['parameter1'];
```

---

Note: `QS['parameter']` is the same as `QS.parameter`

---

J1 J5 [iJS](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=iJS) [iDOC](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=iDOC)