# How get item ID in JSLink on DisplayForm

Tags: 2013, javascript, jslink

I'm customizing the `DisplayForm` of a list, and I want put a button on footer to `EditForm`, but in the `ctx` has no edit form url and no `CurrentItem.ID`.

How can I do this?

Comment: ID can be retrieved from the Query String in URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting from `ctx`

```
var itemId = ctx.FormContext.itemAttributes.Id;
```

I have executed above code under `OnPreRender` & `OnPostRender` both. So you can use it where you need it.

I think it is easier to get from *Query String* rather than from `ctx.FormContext`.

As per [Asad](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/41513/asad-refai)'s comment, Getting from *Query String*

```
var itemId = GetUrlKeyValue('ID');
```

Have a look on this [answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/159290/21421) by [Danny Engelman](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/32871/danny-engelman) to read more about *Query String.*

Comment: Which one you have used? *query string* or `ctx.FormContext.itemAttributes.Id`?

Comment: For now _query string_. But is good to know about `FormContext.itemAttributes`. :D

Comment: Hey, u know how extract the user name from user field (`ctx.CurrentItem.Author`)?

Comment: use `console.dir(ctx)` in `OnPreRender` and see what's in it. I just find it (`ctx.FormContext.itemAttributes.Id`) this way

Comment: Author is in `ctx.ListData.Items[0].Author`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32047/discussion-between-atish-dipongkor-and-carlos).