# Reference SP scripts in html page in app

Tags: javascript, app, sharepoint-addin

I am trying to make an html page in an app, and I want to be able to get: `SP.Utilities` and `_spPageContextInfo`, which scripts do I need to add to my html in order to make it work?

I am in Office 365. I've tried the following scripts, but nothing worked:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>

<script src="/_layouts/15/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/init.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.Core.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.Debug.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.Debug.js></script>
```

anyone tried it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**_spPageContextInfo**:

`_spPageContextInfo` have some useful values that added to SharePoint master page. But SharePoint apps built to be isolated and light.

You can’t access `_spPageContextInfo` form App pages, but you can access same values by different ways:

1. URL strings and tokens in apps for SharePoint: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163816.aspx
2. If then you need more values than not provided by tokens you can access what you want by load `SP.ClientContext`

Example: If you want to get the `webServerRelativeUrl` of the site on which you have installed your app, then simply

```
hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('HostUrl'));
```

> **Note**: You don't need to add any JS files, you get this from query
>   string

Refer [_spPageContextInfo is not defined](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/officeapps/en-US/c0cce789-1c7c-4e4a-8158-213ee5eb6355/napa-app-sppagecontextinfo-is-not-defined?forum=appsforsharepoint) for more details.

**SP.Utilities**:

The `SP.Utilities` can be referred directly from code. For example if you want to send an email, the below snippet is used in the function.

```
appweburl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";
```

Comment: thank you. but how do I load SP.ClientContext? which scripts are necessary for it?

Comment: for example, I want to get the current webServerRelativeUrl, I used to use _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl , what do I use now?

Comment: @DavidHemsey [Info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj245759.aspx) on `SP.ClientContext`.  Once you have a `ClientContext` object, you can get the current web and its server relative url.  You won't need `_spPageContextInfo`.

Comment: @wjervis is correct

Comment: thank you guys, but. Again guys, what are the scripts required to get client context, as stated in my question it's not working for me. What scripts should I use to get client content, we can forget about spPageContextInfo now..

Comment: @DavidHemsey You probably need `SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded`, as stated in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25786685/3581857) answer.  Please add error details to your question so we can better help you.

Comment: @DavidHemsey You get the web server relative url, from the query string. See the updated answer.

Comment: hi all, I used these and they worked, but are they all necessary: 

 <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.init.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/15/core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/init.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.Core.js"></script>


I just want someone to tell me which files to add.

Comment: I copied pasted your code, for the HostUrl, and it gave me **Uncaught ReferenceError: getQueryStringParameter is not defined(…)**

Comment: Am I missing a script?

Comment: Refer this article http://www.mavention.com/blog/sharePoint-app-reading-data-from-host-web . You will get this method. You write this function in your script.

Comment: I am getting: **Uncaught ReferenceError: IsNullOrUndefined is not defined** on core.js and **Uncaught ReferenceError: NotifyScriptLoadedAndExecuteWaitingJobs is not defined** on sp.init.js.

Comment: I don't see the getQueryStringParameter in either the app web, or the host web. It's not even loaded in the host web. Is it a valid sharepoint function?

Comment: ``getQueryStringParameter`` is declared in some MSDN examples (and everyone copy/pastes those), Not necessary as multiple SP libraries provide the same functionality: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159289/what-does-this-code-getquerystringparameter-do/159290#159290

Comment: Its not referenced in any file.. But u need to write it.. If you notice the article carefully, you will find this function. Just copy paste and start using it.

Comment: one more question, any difference between sp.core.js, and core.js?

Answer (score 0):

- Load a regular SP page with a ListView
- Open F12 developer tools
- Type the name of the function, without ()
- click the function definition

F12 source panel will open with the file the function is defined in

Comment: _spPageContextInfo doesn't appear to be a function.

Comment: it is an object, not a function. Open all sources you think they are used in, then use Ctrf- search in the Sources panel

Comment: I didn't understand.. what should I do to make it available?