# getQueryStringParameter is not defined

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin

I have a SharePoint hosted app and I am trying to pull the `SPHostUrl` out of the app Url for REST calls.

Everything I read tells me to use the below but for some reason I am getting an error

```
'GetQueryStringParameter' is undefined
```

I have tried in a couple of different browsers and even tried just a simple command in the console using the browser developer tools but it seems `GetQueryStringParameter()` is not a valid function? am I missing something?

**URL**

```
http://app-cb941ae4f1f18e.app.dragon.dev/sites/smrgol/AppPartTest/Pages/Default.aspx?SPHostUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flair%2Edragon%2Edev%2Fsites%2Fsmrgol&SPLanguage=en%2DUS&SPClientTag=2&SPProductNumber=15%2E0%2E4763%2E1000&SPAppWebUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fapp%2Dcb941ae4f1f18e%2Eapp%2Edragon%2Edev%2Fsites%2Fsmrgol%2FAppPartTest
```

**References in `Default.aspx`**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/App.js"></script>
```

**Line in `App.js`**

```
var hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definition of `getQueryStringParameter` should look like following. Check it in your App.js file.

```
function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
var params =
document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
var strParams = "";
for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
    var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
    if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
        return singleParam[1];
}
```

It is not needed actually, you can get by following way.

```
var spHostUrl = GetUrlKeyValue('SPHostUrl');
```

See following post for more explanation by [Danny Engelman](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/32871/danny-engelman)

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/159290/21421

Comment: Thanks, I was wrongly assuming it was included in one of the js libraries. it works once I add it in but I prefer the second method you gave :)

Comment: Credit goes to this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159289/what-does-this-code-getquerystringparameter-do/159290#159290. Give a up vote there. I personally came to know about it after this post.