# Accessing JavaScript libraries for basic tasks

Tags: javascript, cewp

I ran into an error while trying to gain access to the required libraries for JavaScript development.  I copied this code straight from Microsoft's documentation, however when it is executed on my page through a **content editor web part**, I get the following error:

> Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or null reference

It doesn't like the split call in the `getQueryStringParameter()` function.  What exactly is the function trying to do with my `document.URL`, and what does the URL not have that causes it to not get processed properly?

```
<script 
src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js" 
type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script
type="text/javascript"
src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var hostweburl;

// Load the required SharePoint libraries.
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Get the URI decoded URLs.
    hostweburl =
        decodeURIComponent(
            getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl")
    );

    // The js files are in a URL in the form:
    // web_url/_layouts/15/resource_file
    var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";

    // Load the js files and continue to
    // the execOperation function.
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",
        function () {
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", execOperation);
        }
    );
});

// Function to execute basic operations.
function execOperation() {

    // Continue your program flow here.

}

// Function to retrieve a query string value.
// For production purposes you may want to use
// a library to handle the query string.
function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
    var params =
        document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    var strParams = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
        if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
            return singleParam[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: How your  URL looks like?

Comment: https://urimdev.byu.edu/cmoodysite/Scripts%20Test/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Comment: I mostly just don't know what the getQueryStringParameter() is trying to achieve, so it is difficult to know what to change.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/159290/21421

Comment: the code splits the string on the questionmark, then takes the **second** =[1] part from it.... what if document.URL has no questionmark (thus parameters) ? This is incorrect code everyone re-posts in blogposts

Comment: What should scriptbase be then for getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", execOperation) to work properly?  If I know what it is looking for I can readjust the getQueryString() properly