# office365- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined, querystring parameter fails

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app

I created an SharePoint Hosted App in this app I am using Two form for saving data into list. When I click on save button to save data into list  data is saved into list and redirect to another page  that have another form to save data into list but facing the error on that page-

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined dut to
>   fail querystring parameter

I am using the following code to access appweburl and hostweburl-

```
hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));

var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";

var context = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostweburl);
web = appContextSite.get_web();
```

What I have to do to fix this issue , please suggest anyone.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The  `getQueryStringParameter` function everyone copies from MSDN examples is not flawless;

It fails when there are no parameters (after the ? ) on the QueryString.

The function is totally unneeded anyway: [What does this code getQueryStringParameter do?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159289/what-does-this-code-getquerystringparameter-do/159290#159290)