# how to get this error solved? error is saying ...expected identifier in function getdetails

Tags: jquery, ajax

Below Code giving an error called

> "expected identifier in function getdetails"

```
$( document ).ready(function() { 

    qString = getdetails();
});


function getdetails( {
 var result = window.location.href.split("?ID=")[1];
 return result;
});
```

Can you please assist me to resolve it?

Comment: Is getdetails(); function returns something?
If yes then add the whole code in the comment.

Comment: getdetails() will return ID number

Comment: You need to only return your result.

Answer (score 2):

Your code fails because the Function declaration is wrong:

You do:

```
function getdetails( {dosomething} )
```

But the correct way of declaring a function is:

```
function getdetails() {dosomething}
```

#### BUT, More potential errors:

Your code tries to extract the ID value when it is the **first** QueryString parameter in the URL

So it fails:

- When ID is not immediatly after the **?** QueryString identifier
- When there is no ID in the QueryString

SharePoint provides you at least 4 ways of getting a QueryString value:

[What does this code getQueryStringParameter do?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159289/what-does-this-code-getquerystringparameter-do/159290#159290)

Answer (score 1):

var result;
$( document ).ready(function() { 
     getdetails();
     var qString = result;
});

function getdetails() 
{
   result = window.location.href.split("?ID=")[1];
return result;
}

Answer (score 0):

Please try below mentioned code.

```
var result;
$( document ).ready(function() { 
     getdetails();
     var qString = result;
});

function getdetails() 
{
   result = window.location.href.split("?ID=")[1];
}
```

Comment: qString = getdetails();....control is not reaching the functn

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please try it.

Comment: Is that working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the getdetails function.Code is inside ()

```
 function getdetails(){ var result = window.location.href.split("?ID=")[1]; return result;};
```