# Change the text of a page based on link Clicked

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, html

we have several pages with same contents the only difference is the author.
instead of creating multiple pages for each author in sharepoint can we not change the author and may be very few select keys based on the hyperlink clicked to get to the page ?

Comment: exactly not getting what you want.can you share more details?

Comment: Simply put. I want to be able to change the content/text of a page based on hyperlink on the other. say if the text of the hyperlink is "mark" that text will be replace author keyword on the page linked to the hyperlink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass variables in the QueryString (everything after the **?** in the URL)

Then use JavaScript to read those Parameters ([What does this code getQueryStringParameter do?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159289/what-does-this-code-getquerystringparameter-do)) and display content

Comment: thanks danny , how do i replace the keyword "Author" in the body with  page from text passed as QueryString ?

Comment: You have to learn JavaScript (and Conten/Scrip Editor WebParts) to do that, the link gets you the JS code to read the QueryString, then you use the ``document.querySelector`` JS function  to targer a location in the HTML page, and replace its ``innerHTML``. Note most will tell you to use jQuery, but that requires you to load a 90 KB jQuery library (extending your learning track) ``document.querySelector`` is standard vanilla JS code since IE**9**, so all jQuery answers are telling you to code the way we did in the (far) IE past

Comment: Tip: Learn to use F12 Snippets in the Chrome Browser, it allows you to code *against* SharePoint without reloading the page every time; saves you heaps of trial/error reloads. When your **snippet** works, you paste it into a Content/Script Editor WebPart...... Remember; You are getting into SharePoint programming now... learning new things takes BS&T

Comment: it looks pretty straightforward and easy however i am having trouble getting the output. i sent the text over by appending url?Author=mathew and was able to see it in the url of the next page. in the script editor i used <script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    var value=getQueryStringParameter('Author');
   document.querySelector(".aap").innerHTML = var;
  }
</script>

Comment: i just put a dummy class 'aap' <td class="ms-rteTable-default aap">Author</td> to identify the tag and replace the inner html

Comment: 'aap'? Are you Dutch?

Comment: naa it's just random letters i picked up :). but the above are not working . i have added the function in a script editor as advised. am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: Does this function run on page load or do we have to have some mechanism to call in on page load ?

Comment: okay, take one step back and learn to execute JavaScript **after** pageload

Comment: how do i do that ? i am stuck.

Comment: Got it working with this GetUrlKeyValue :)